# Слияние двух массивов с одинаковыми ключами

Tags: php, массивы

Есть 2 массива:

```
$array1 = [
            'Москва' = 
                    [ 0 => 'значение',
                      1 => 'значение',
                      2 => 'значение',
                    ],
            'Киев' = 
                    [ 0 => 'значение',
                      1 => 'значение',
                      2 => 'значение',
                    ]

          ];

  $array2 = [
            'Москва' = 
                    [ 0 => 'значение',
                      1 => 'значение',
                      2 => 'значение',
                    ],
            'Киев' = 
                    [ 0 => 'значение',
                      1 => 'значение',
                      2 => 'значение',
                    ]

          ];
```

Можно ли получить такой массив?

```
$array3 = [
            'Москва' = 
                    [ 0 => 'значение',
                      1 => 'значение',
                      2 => 'значение',
                    ],
            'Киев' = 
                    [ 0 => 'значение',
                      1 => 'значение',
                      2 => 'значение',
                    ],
            'Москва' = 
                    [ 0 => 'значение',
                      1 => 'значение',
                      2 => 'значение',
                    ],
            'Киев' = 
                    [ 0 => 'значение',
                      1 => 'значение',
                      2 => 'значение',
                    ]

          ];
```

Пробовал разными встроенными функциями, но они только добавляют значение второго массива в первый.

Comment: Не получится в один массив напихать одинаковых индексов. Их можно либо объединять, либо переписывать один другим.

Comment: понял, спасибо!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ещё вариант в коллекцию ответов:

```
$array1 = [
    'Москва' => ['значение1', 'значение2', 'значение3'],
    'Киев' => ['значение4', 'значение5', 'значение6']
];

$array2 = [
    'Москва' => ['значение7', 'значение8', 'значение9'],
    'Киев' => ['значение10', 'значение11', 'значение12']
];

$array = [];

if (count($array1) == count($array2)) {
    array_map(function($a1, $a2)use(&$array, &$array1){
        $k = key($array1);
        next($array1);
        $array[$k] = array_merge($a1, $a2);
    }, $array1, $array2);
}

echo '<pre>', print_r($array, true), '</pre>';
```

Результат:

```
Array
(
    [Москва] => Array
        (
            [0] => значение1
            [1] => значение2
            [2] => значение3
            [3] => значение7
            [4] => значение8
            [5] => значение9
        )

    [Киев] => Array
        (
            [0] => значение4
            [1] => значение5
            [2] => значение6
            [3] => значение10
            [4] => значение11
            [5] => значение12
        )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Получить массив с одинаковыми ключами не возможно.
Но можно свести массивы, если уже очень нужно, например, так:

```
$array1 = [
    'Москва' => [
        'значение1',
        'значение1',
        'значение1',
    ],
    'Киев' => [
        'значение1',
        'значение1',
        'значение1',
    ]
];

$array2 = [
    'Москва' => [
        'значение2',
        'значение2',
        'значение2',
    ],
    'Киев' => [
        'значение2',
        'значение2',
        'значение2',
    ]
];

// Назначаем переменным масивы
list($source, $dest) = [$array1, $array2];

// Определяем, в каком массиве больше элементов, тот и будем перебирать 
if(count($source)<count($dest)){
    list($source, $dest) = [$array2, $array1];
}

$res = [];          
foreach($source as $key=>$value){
    $res[$key][] = $value;
    $res[$key][] = $dest[$key];
};

var_dump($res);
```

На выходе получаем такой массив:

```
array(2) {
  ["Москва"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(17) "значение1"
      [1]=>
      string(17) "значение1"
      [2]=>
      string(17) "значение1"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(17) "значение2"
      [1]=>
      string(17) "значение2"
      [2]=>
      string(17) "значение2"
    }
  }
  ["Киев"]=>
  array(2) {
    [0]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(17) "значение1"
      [1]=>
      string(17) "значение1"
      [2]=>
      string(17) "значение1"
    }
    [1]=>
    array(3) {
      [0]=>
      string(17) "значение2"
      [1]=>
      string(17) "значение2"
      [2]=>
      string(17) "значение2"
    }
  }
}
```